# alternative for deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies to configure the services

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to configure the services in my azureb2c project, I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies package however the package is deprecated, any alternative for the deprecated package?
I am getting an error near CookieAuthenticationOptions if I remove the deprecated package

```
 var services = builder.Services;
 services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.AccessDeniedPath))
     {
         options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");
     }
 });
```

Comment: What is the framework of your App?

Comment: What's your current asp.net core version now? Actually there is no need to install it now. You could directly using the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;` namespace.

Comment: currently, I am using .net 8

Comment: Will post an answer in detail

Answer (score 1):

I haven't Installed any NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`

I have tried to add the code which you have given in .NET Core 8 Web API.

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
------
```

- You can see the prompt
  [image]
- After adding the `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, the namespace is included automatically in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
```

Thanks @Brando Zhang for the comment.

Yes, as mentioned by Brando, no need to Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` package.

- You can even check the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples) for different Core versions.
- The `.csproj` does not have any Package Installed related to Authentication Cookie.
- Few packages related to Authentication are part of default SDK. You can see the package is included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

[image]

But I can see few versions of the package are not marked as Deprecated.

[image]

Comment: Even I have tried with Core 6 and 7 Versions, same is applicable.